# Trying to create an array, "error: '.class' expected"

Tags: java, arrays

Here's my code:

```
public static String[][] displayPlay()
{
   String[][] board = new String[10][10];
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
         board[i][j] = ".";
      }
   }
   return board[][];
}
```

(This is meant to create a 10x10 array of "."s)

The error message in the title points to the end of the line `return board[][]`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to just return board

Change `return board[][];` to `return board;`

Answer (score 1):

You must return `board`, not `board [][]`.